# As an instructor, how do I get a list of enrolled students (only) for my course?

Tags: desire2learn

As an instructor user, what Valence Learning Framework API calls must I make to fetch back a list of all the students (only) enrolled in one of my courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two principal ways to get a list of the people enrolled in a D2L LE class org unit; the right call you should use depends most upon the back-end LMS's configuration that you're working with:

- [GET /d2l/api/le/{ver}/{orgUnitId}/classlist/](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-classlist-)

  This will retrieve all the users enrolled in the org unit that the system has configured to appear in the class; in some organizations, this might consist of students only, but it's most likely that this call will mix in instructors, tutors, and the like as well as students. So this might, or might not, be appropriate for your needs.

  One thing you can try in combination with this route to distinguish students from others in the course is to focus on those who are *gradeable*; make the classlist call, and then for each user in the classlist, request a grade value for a known grade item. If the user is a student or other role that is participating in the course and being graded, you will know from that second call; non-gradeable users will not have grade values associated with their enrollment. This will help you focus on the aspects of the person's enrollment in the course without necessarily focussing on the details of their enrolled role (some organizations treat role information as sensitive).
- [GET /d2l/api/lp/{ver}/enrollments/orgUnits/{orgUnitId}/users/?roleId={roleId}](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-orgUnits-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-users-)

  This call will retrieve all the users enrolled in the org unit, and you can filter the retrieved list by role ID (so you can list only "student" users, by their role Id). If the organization has more than one kind of student role, then you will need to know that so you can fetch all the possible student roles. Or, you can simply make the call without the `roleId` query parameter and filter the results after fetching based on the embedded role information you get back.

  However, your instructor user may not have the right permissions to make this call; some organizations limit the access to the enrollment information calls like this to administrative users only.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using the grade object method to determine if user is a student will, by default, only returns **20 items**.  You can override by specifying pageSize parameter with the call, but you may run in to the same permissions issue if you do not have the appropriate permissions.

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#get--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-grades-(gradeObjectId)-values-